# JNI_CreateJavaVM always fails

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to create a `JVM` through windows service but `JNI_CreateJavaVM` always fails. Here is my code,

```
DWORD WINAPI InvokeMain(LPVOID lpParam) {
    // HACK to hang the function
    while(1) {
        if( (_access( "e:\\file", 0 )) != -1 ) {
            break;
        }
    }
    //Load the JVM Dll
    HINSTANCE ghDllInstance = LoadLibrary(L"E:\\jdk1.6.0_26\\jre\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll");

    if( ghDllInstance == 0) {
        Log("Failed to load jvm dll\n");
        return FALSE;
    }
    //resolve the function pointer JNI_CreateJVM
    CreateJavaVM createJVMStart = (CreateJavaVM)GetProcAddress(ghDllInstance, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");

    JavaVMOption options[2];
    options[0].optionString    = "-Djava.class.path=e:\\win\\product\\lib"; // application class path 
    options[1].optionString    = " start";

    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    vm_args.version            = JNI_VERSION_1_6; //JNI Version 1.4 and above
    vm_args.options            = options;
    vm_args.nOptions           = 2;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;


    //Create the JVM
    JavaVM *vmStart;
    JNIEnv *env;
    jint res = createJVMStart(&vmStart, (void **)&env, &vm_args);
    if (res < 0)  {
        Log( "Error creating JVM");
        return FALSE;
    }       
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: It might help if you said HOW it fails.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are loading the JVM instead of linking to it? Linking makes the code much easier.

Comment: @EJP: Can you please explain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used the 1.6 VM. But I am pretty sure that `start` is  not a valid option.
And since you pass `JNI_FALSE` to `ignoreUnrecognized` theVM is not created.
I guess start is a param to your program. But then you need   to pass it to main function yourself.